# Trying to programmatically resize OpenGL cube

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

I am trying to implement functionality to resize my OpenGL cube, either via slider or button press. I have toyed around with a few things, none of which seem to work. The first thing I tried to do was create a function that returns the vertex array, and call this on button press passing in the value I would like to scale the cube by. This does not update the cube being rendered, however. I next tried to use `glScalef`, but this only made my shape disappear completely (i was scaling by non-zero values). Since it is a cube, ideally I can store one variable that will contain the 'size' of the cube, and use that variable to construct my cube, then when that variable changes, the cube will be redrawn. Can anyone offer some help? :)

```
import React

//
// MARK: - View Controller
//

/// Our subclass of GLKViewController to perform drawing, and logic updates using OpenGL ES.
final class ViewController: GLKViewController {
 private let childView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 600, height: 300));
  /// Vertices array that stores 4 Vertex objects used to draw and color a square on screen.
    lazy var scale = 1;
    
    lazy var Vertices = resizeCube(scale: 2);
  
  /// Array used to store the indices in the order we want to draw the triangles of our square.
  var Indices: [GLubyte] = [
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0,
    4,5,6,
    6,7,4,
    3,2,5,
    5,4,3,
    7,6,1,
    1,0,7,
    1,6,5,
    5,2,1,
    3,4,7,
    7,0,3
  ]
    
    @IBAction func highScoreButtonTapped(sender : UIButton) {
      NSLog("Hello")
      guard
        let jsCodeLocation = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main", withExtension: "jsbundle"), ((try? Data(contentsOf: jsCodeLocation)) != nil)
        else { return }

      let rootView = RCTRootView(
        bundleURL: jsCodeLocation,
          moduleName: "MyReactNativeApp",
          initialProperties: nil,
          launchOptions: nil
      )
        childView.addSubview(rootView)
        rootView.frame = childView.bounds;
        self.view.addSubview(childView);
        self.scale += 1;
        self.viewDidLoad();
      // let vc = UIViewController()
        // vc.view.addSubview(rootView)
       // self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
      //self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  
  //
  // MARK: - Variables And Properties
  //
  
  /// Reference to provide easy access to our EAGLContext.
  private var context: EAGLContext?
  
  /// Effect to facilitate having to write shaders in order to achieve shading and lighting.
  private var effect = GLKBaseEffect()
  
  /// Used to store and determine the rotation value of our drawn geometry.
  public var rotation: Float = 0.0
  
  /// Element buffer object. Stores the indices that tell OpenGL what vertices to draw.
  private var ebo = GLuint()
  
  /// Vertex buffer object. Stores our vertex information within the GPU's memory.
  private var vbo = GLuint()
  
  /// Vertex array object. Stores vertex attribute calls that facilitate future drawing. Instead of having to bind/unbind
  /// several buffers constantly to perform drawn, you can simply bind your VAO, make the vertex attribute cals you would
  /// to draw elements on screen, and then whenever you want to draw you simply bind your VAO and it stores those other
  /// vertex attribute calls.
  private var vao = GLuint()
  
  //
  // MARK: - Initialization
  //
  
  /// Method to deinitialize and perform cleanup when the view controller is removed from memory.
  deinit {
    // Delete buffers, cleanup memory, etc.
    tearDownGL()
  }
  
  //
  // MARK: - Private Methods
  //
    private func resizeCube(scale: Int) -> [Vertex]{
        let Vertices = [
        Vertex(x:  GLfloat(scale), y: GLfloat(-scale), z: GLfloat(scale), r: 1, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1),
        Vertex(x:  1, y:  1, z: 1, r: 0, g: 1, b: 0, a: 1),
        Vertex(x: -1, y:  1, z: 1, r: 0, g: 0, b: 1, a: 1),
        Vertex(x: -1, y: -1, z: 1, r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1),
        Vertex(x:  1, y: -1, z: -1, r: 1, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1),
        Vertex(x:  1, y:  1, z: -1, r: 0, g: 1, b: 0, a: 1),
        Vertex(x: -1, y:  1, z: -1, r: 0, g: 0, b: 1, a: 1),
        Vertex(x: -1, y: -1, z: -1, r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1),
        ]
        return Vertices;
    }
    
  /// Setup the current OpenGL context, generate and find necessary buffers, and store geometry data in memory (buffers).
  private func setupGL() {
    // Create an OpenGL ES 3.0 context and store it in our local variable.
    context = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES3)
    
    // Set the current EAGLContext to our context we created when performing OpenGL setup.
    EAGLContext.setCurrent(context)
    
    // Perform checks and unwrap options in order to perform more OpenGL setup.
    if let view = self.view as? GLKView, let context = context {
      // Set our view's context to the EAGLContext we just created.s
      view.context = context

      // Set ourselves as delegates of GLKViewControllerDelegate
      delegate = self
    }
    
    // Helper variables to identify the position and color attributes for OpenGL calls.
    let vertexAttribColor = GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.color.rawValue)
    let vertexAttribPosition = GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.position.rawValue)
    
    // The size, in memory, of a Vertex structure.
    let vertexSize = MemoryLayout<Vertex>.stride
    // The byte offset, in memory, of our color information within a Vertex object.
    let colorOffset = MemoryLayout<GLfloat>.stride * 3
    // Swift pointer object that stores the offset of the color information within our Vertex structure.
    let colorOffsetPointer = UnsafeRawPointer(bitPattern: colorOffset)
    
    // VAO
    
    // Generate and bind a vertex array object.
    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &vao)
    glBindVertexArrayOES(vao)
    
    // VBO
    
    // Generatea a buffer for our vertex buffer object.
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo)
    // Bind the vertex buffer object we just generated (created).
    glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), vbo)
    // Pass data for our vertices to the vertex buffer object.
    glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), Vertices.size(), Vertices, GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW))
    
    // Enable the position vertex attribute to then specify information about how the position of a vertex is stored.
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexAttribPosition)
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexAttribPosition, 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(UInt8(GL_FALSE)), GLsizei(vertexSize), nil)
    
    // Enable the colors vertex attribute to then specify information about how the color of a vertex is stored.
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexAttribColor)
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexAttribColor, 4, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(UInt8(GL_FALSE)), GLsizei(vertexSize), colorOffsetPointer)
    
    // EBO
    
    // Generatea a buffer for our element buffer object.
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo)
    // Bind the element buffer object we just generated (created).
    glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), ebo)
    // Pass data for our element indices to the element buffer object.
    glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), Indices.size(), Indices, GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW))
    // Unbind all buffers and objects.
    
    // Unbind the vertex buffer and the vertex array object.
    glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), 0)
    glBindVertexArrayOES(0)
    glEnable(GLenum(GL_CULL_FACE));
  }
  
  
  /// Perform cleanup, and delete buffers and memory.
  private func tearDownGL() {
    // Set the current EAGLContext to our context. This ensures we are deleting buffers against it and potentially not a
    // different context.
    EAGLContext.setCurrent(context)
    
    // Delete the vertex array object, the element buffer object, and the vertex buffer object.
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vao)
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo)
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo)
    
    // Set the current EAGLContext to nil.
    EAGLContext.setCurrent(nil)
    
    // Then nil out or variable that references our EAGLContext.
    context = nil
  }
  
  //
  // MARK: - Touch Handling
  //
  
  /// Used to detect when a tap occurs on screen so we can pause updates of our program.
  ///
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - touches: The touches that occurred on screen.
  ///   - event: Describes the user interactions in the app.
  func touche(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // Pause or unpause updating our program.
    isPaused = !isPaused
  }
  
  //
  // MARK: - View Controller
  //
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
      print("Button tapped")
    }
  
  /// Called when the view controller's view is loaded into memory.
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Set child view x y cordinate and size.
    childView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200)

    // Set child view background color.
    childView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    // Perform OpenGL setup, create buffers, pass geometry data to memory.
    setupGL()
  }
}


//
// MARK: - GLKViewController Delegate
//
extension ViewController: GLKViewControllerDelegate {
  func glkViewControllerUpdate(_ controller: GLKViewController) {
    let aspect = fabsf(Float(view.bounds.size.width) / Float(view.bounds.size.height))
    let projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(85.0), aspect, 1, 10.0)
    effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix
    
    var modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0, -6.0)
    rotation += 90 * Float(timeSinceLastUpdate)
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(rotation), 1, 1, 0)
    effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix
  }
}

//
// MARK: - GLKView Delegate
//

/// Extension to implement the GLKViewDelegate methods.
extension ViewController {

  /// Draw the view's contents using OpenGL ES.
  ///
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - view: The GLKView object to redraw contents into.
  ///   - rect: Rectangle that describes the area to draw into.
  override func glkView(_ view: GLKView, drawIn rect: CGRect) {
    // Set the color we want to clear the screen with (before drawing) to black.
    glClearColor(0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 1.0)
    // Clear the contents of the screen (the color buffer) with the black color we just set.
    glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
    
    // Compiles the shaders for drawing and binds them to the current context.
    effect.prepareToDraw()
    
    // We bind our vertex array object, essentially indicating we want to use its information to draw geometry on screen.
    glBindVertexArrayOES(vao);
    // Make the call to draw elements on screen. We indicate we want to draw triangles, specify the number of vertices we
    // want to draw via our indices array, and also tell OpenGL what variable type is used to store the index information.
    glDrawElements(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLES), GLsizei(Indices.count), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), nil)
    // Unbind the vertex array object so future calls don't accidentally use it.
    glBindVertexArrayOES(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: As an option, you can use the scale matrix to dynamically resize of object.